# What should I do to communicate with GSM module?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, gsm

Sorry, im a beginner, i tried to program an automatic doorlock using sms. But, I dont understand what happen with this error, what should I do? Add library? The error said that Pstring wasnt declared, but i dont know how to declare this.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include "SIM900.h"
#include "sms.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include "sms.h"

SMSGSM sms;
boolean started=false;
char buffer[160];
char smsbuffer[160];
char n[20];
int pintu=5;
int buttonState;
int lastButtonState = LOW;
long lastDebounceTime = 0;
long debounceDelay = 50;
boolean st=false;
int buzzer=6;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(pintu,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buzzer,OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(pintu,LOW);
 if (gsm.begin(9600))
 {
  started=true; 
   digitalWrite(buzzer,HIGH);
   delay(100);
   digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
   delay(100);
   digitalWrite(buzzer,HIGH);
   delay(100);
   digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
   delay(100);
   digitalWrite(buzzer,HIGH);
   delay(100);
   digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
   delay(100);
  }
   if(started)
  {
   delsms();
   sms.SendSMS("08970869443","Pintu SMS Menyala");
  }
  else{digitalWrite(buzzer,HIGH); delay(2000); digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
  }


   }

   void loop()
   {

   int pos=0;
  if (gsm.begin(9600))
  {
  if (started){
  pos=sms.IsSMSPresent(SMS_ALL);
  if(pos)
  {
   sms.GetSMS(pos,n,smsbuffer,100);
   delay(2000);
    if(!strcmp(smsbuffer,"bukapintu"))
    {
      PString str(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    str.begin();
    str.print("Pintu Dibuka");
    digitalWrite(pintu,HIGH);
   // String a=str
    sms.SendSMS(n,buffer);
    }
    if(!strcmp(smsbuffer,"tutuppintu"))
    {
      PString str(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    str.begin();
    str.print("Kunci Pintu Ditutup");
    digitalWrite(pintu,LOW);
   // String a=str
    sms.SendSMS(n,buffer);
    }
    delsms();
   }
   }
   }
   }

   void delsms()
   {
   for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {  
     int pos=sms.IsSMSPresent(SMS_ALL);
    if (pos!=0)
   {
    if (sms.DeleteSMS(pos)==1){}else{}
   }
   }
   }
```

Error message :

```
     Arduino: 1.6.7 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

      D:\Kuliah\Project\Skripsi\pintu_sms\pintu_sms.ino: In function 'void loop()':

      pintu_sms:67: error: 'PString' was not declared in this scope

       PString str(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

       ^

      pintu_sms:67: error: expected ';' before 'str'

       PString str(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

               ^

     pintu_sms:68: error: 'str' was not declared in this scope

     str.begin();

     ^

    pintu_sms:76: error: 'PString' was not declared in this scope

       PString str(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

       ^

    pintu_sms:76: error: expected ';' before 'str'

       PString str(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

               ^

     pintu_sms:77: error: 'str' was not declared in this scope

     str.begin();

     ^

     exit status 1
  'PString' was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not know what PString is. It is not declared in any of the libraries you have included.

You could rewrite to something like this.

```
strcat(buffer, "Pintu Dibuka");
n = strlen(buffer);
digitalWrite(pintu,HIGH);
sms.SendSMS(n,buffer);
```

Please change the other block in the same way.

There are more errors. You also need to change "int n[20]" to "int n".

That is a good start.

Cheers!

Comment: I tried what you told to me, but still error

Comment: or i missed any libraries?

Comment: Yes there are more errors of the same type (using PString). You might have intended to include that? Cut-and-pasting code?

Comment: Try this library http://arduiniana.org/libraries/PString/.